# Multilevel Multiple Imputation (MICE) with categorical/factor variable?

Tags: r, imputation, factors, multi-level, r-mice

I have a dataset where I am trying to use multiple imputation with the packages `mice`, `miceadds` and `micemd` for a categorical/factor variable in a multilevel setting. I am able to use the method `2l.2stage.pois` for a continuous variable, which works quite well. The imputation for the categorical variable also works with `polyreg`, but this does not make use of the multilevel data.

Here is replicable code that illustrates my problem.

```
dat <- data.frame(x=rep(c("A", "B"), 50),
                  y=rep(c(10:14), 20),
                  r=rep(c(1:50), 2),
                  z=rep(c(1:4), 25))

dat[40:44, c("x")] <- NA
dat[60:64, c("y")] <- NA
dat[80:84, c("r")] <- NA

predm <- mice::make.predictorMatrix(data=dat)

predm[, c("z")] <- -2
predm[, c("r")] <- 3
predm[row(predm) == col(predm)] <- 0
meth <- c("x"="polyreg", "y"="2l.2stage.pois", "r"="", "z"="")

imputed = mice(dat, method=meth, predictorMatrix=predm, m=1, maxit=1)
imp <- complete(imputed)

table(imp$x, dat$x, useNA = "always")
table(imp$y, dat$y, useNA = "always")
```

In essence, I am trying to substitute `polyreg` with something that should probably start with `2l.`. I have tried `2l.2stage.bin`, but that is for binary variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no multilevel polynomial regression imputation implemented in `mice` or adjacent `R` packages. A workaround would be to use `pmm` instead. Experientially, `pmm` works well for categorical variables in unclustered data, see also the advice in the `mice` book [FIMD](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-categorical.html).

Multilevel `pmm` methods are implemented in `miceadds` as `2l.pmm` and `micemd` as `2l.2stage.pmm`.